# Drupal on AWS for 3000 users, what instance to use?

Tags: amazon-ec2, drupal-7

I am looking at installing Drupal on Amazon Web services to host a staff training website & staff newsletter. There will be no heavy custom coding just a very standard drupal install.

The day to day use will be pretty low, but there will be time were nearly 3000 users will hit the site with in a hour.

Any advice on which instance size to use? if to use a load balancer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depeneds on many factors. The factors revolve around the question: how optimized are you? If you are not optimized, I'm not sure even the 7.2 GB will be enough. If correctly optimized, it probably will.

Optimization tips? Tell us what this site is about. Mostly static files, not expecting a lot of users really login in? YOU MUST HAVE [BOOST](http://drupal.org/project/boost) INSTALLED. Also, use aws cloudfront and get a 3.4 GB instance, it should be enough. (needless to say, all static files should go to S3).

Did you mean that 3000 users will be login in within an hour? well, that can be tricky... If the surge in users is just for a couple of hours, don't be cheap. Get a huge instance just for a couple of hours. The money is worth all the optimizations you can do...